# Form Validation error: relative jump and sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, validation, page-jump

On one of my pages, I have a web form and a sticky header.

When a user tries to submit this form using a [modern-ish browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) but has not filled in the required fields, an error balloon is displayed (as expected).

The problem is the sticky header, which hides the input field, as shown here ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qr8y1Lw/)):

[image: Form validation error pointing on sticky header]

Now, my question is:

Is there a sensible way to prevent this behaviour and add some pixels to the relative page-jump caused by submit event, when `form.checkValidity()` is false?

I've added my current implementation [as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28024492/766783).

*(N.B. You could argue whether a sticky header is beneficial at all or not, but this discussion shall be taken at [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My current implementation **for evaluation**: http://jsfiddle.net/je8gttnj/

The gist of it is the following code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'form :submit', function(e) {
  var form;
  if ((form = jQuery(e.target).closest('form')).length !== 1) {
    return;
  }
  if (!form[0].checkValidity || form[0].checkValidity()) {
    return;
  }
  reposition();
});
```

where `reposition()` basically calls `window.scrollBy(0, headerHeight)`:

```
var headerHeight;
var reposition = function() {
  headerHeight || (headerHeight = jQuery('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight() + 50);
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, -headerHeight);
  }, 50);
};
```

Personally, I find this not as nice as it could be, but is does the job.